# Probability to make a free throw at basketball

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A basketball player makes a free throw with probability $0.7$. Find the probability of the following events:

a) A: the player makes his first free throw only on the 4th shot;

b) B: the player makes the first at leat 10 consecutive free throws.

For the first part I've seen it is a Geometric model, so $p_3=0.7 \cdot 0.3^3=0.018$, but for the point b) I did something like: $$P(X \ge 10)=1-P(X<10)=1-P(X \le9)=1-F_X(9)=^{matlab} 1-geopdf(9,0.7)= 5.9049e-06$$

But I am not sure if my aproach is correct for the second part.

Comment: the phrasing is odd, but I think $b$ is just asking for the probability that the player makes the first $10$ free throws, hence $.7^{10}$

Comment: @lulu appears to me to be correct. If the basketball player makes the first ten, it doesn't matter whether they also make the next one, or the one after that- in other words, "at least 10" implies "exactly 10". No distribution modeling necessary.